# Could not read memory at: -375957928, length: 4 - GetLastError: 998 pymem gta 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, script, game

Estou usando a lib do python usando pymem!

Estou com este erro para escrever na memoria do gta 5 (não irei afetar ninguém é para jogar no singleplayer) eu consigui achar os offsets corretos, o pointerscan correto também, tudo pelo cheat engine, quando eu altero o valor do pointerscan ele altera minha munição no gta 5, porém quando eu escrevo esse codigo no python ele me retorna esse erro, mesmo com tudo certo seria isso um bug do pymem?

meu código:

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *
import keyboard

print('Script carregado com sucesso')
teclas = "c"
mem = Pymem("GTA5.exe")
module = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "GTA5.exe").lpBaseOfDll
offsets = [0x38,0x88,0x20,0x18]

def getPointerAddr(base, offsets):
    addr = mem.read_int(base)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            addr = mem.read_int(addr + offset)
    addr = addr + offsets[-1]
    return addr

mem.write_int(getPointerAddr(module + 0x02940BD0, offsets), 9999)
```

my error in game gta 5 / meu erro no game gta 5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programas PYTHON\hackingpython\municaogta5.py", line 21, in <module>
    mem.write_int(getPointerAddr(module + 0x02940BD0, offsets), 9999)
  File "d:\Programas PYTHON\hackingpython\municaogta5.py", line 15, in getPointerAddr
    addr = mem.read_int(addr + offset)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 532, in read_int
    raise pymem.exception.MemoryReadError(address, struct.calcsize('i'), e.error_code)
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: -375957928, length: 4 - GetLastError: 998
```

Comment: Use um debug, ou coloque um print a depois de cada `mem.read_int(addr + offset)`. Já que você tá setando o `addr` e depois usando ele novamente, se o retorno do primeio for um `-375957928` a proxima execução do loop será algo como `-375957928 + offset (assim tentando ler algo negativo)`.

Comment: @Inkeliz Fiz o método de print(), a linha addr = mem.read_int(base) me retornou -1310865280, já a linha 20 não me retornou nada, nela é o erro, porém não sei como posso resolver

Comment: acabei de resgatar outro pointer scan, ele me retornou o erro pymem.exception.WinAPIError: Windows api error, error_code: 299